# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html

Why am I getting this error? This should work, what I'm trying to do is when someone selects the form on the drop down menu and it switches the link, I want whatever was selected last on the select box to stay in the drop down menu but it keeps going all the way back to the top. Thanks

The error I keep getting is

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null**

```html
    <!doctype html>  
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>MyWebsite</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="languageswitcher.css">

      </head>

      <body>

        <header>

          <div id="country-select">
            <form action="" method = "get">
               <select id="locale" name="locale">
     <option value="en_US" title = '0'>English(US)</option>
     <option value="en_GB" title = '1'>English(UK)</option>
     <option value="bg_BG" title = '2'>Bulgarian</option>
     <option value="cs_CS" title = '3'>Czech</option>
     <option value="da_DK" title = '4'>Danish</option>
     <option value="de_DE" title = '5'>German</option>
     <option value="ek_GR" title = '6'>Greek</option>
     <option value="es_ES" title = '7'>Spanish</option>
     <option value="et_ET" title = '8'>Estonian</option>
     <option value="fi_FI" title = '9'>Finnish</option>
     <option value="fr_FR" title = '10'>French</option>
     <option value="hu_HU" title = '11'>Hungarian</option>
     <option value="it_IT" title = '12'>Italian</option>
     <option value="lt_LT" title = '13'>Lithuanian</option>
     <option value="lv_LV" title = '14'>Latvian</option>
     <option value="nl_NL" title = '15'>Dutch</option>
     <option value="no_NO" title = '16'>Norwegian</option>
     <option value="pl_PL" title = '17'>Polish</option>
     <option value="pt_PT" title = '18'>Portugese</option>
     <option value="ro_RO" title = '19'>Romanian</option>
     <option value="sk_SK" title = '20'>Slovak</option>
     <option value="sl_SL" title = '21'>Slovenian</option>
     <option value="sv_SE" title = '22'>Swedish</option>
              </select>
              <input value="Select" type="submit"/>
            </form>
          </div>
        </header>
                   <script>
         // creates the page dynamically
   function GetSelectedItem(){
    var option = document.getElementById("locale").value;
   }
 

   document.getElementById("locale").addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    var selected = event.target.options[ event.target.selectedIndex ].value 
    console.log(selected);
    window.location.hash = selected; 
   });
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Place your `<script>` as `last-child` of `<body>`(Just before closing body tag(`</body>`))

Comment: @Rayon I'm so sorry Rayon I don't know what that means :(  What do you mean last-child? So sorry again I'm just learning

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: Thanks everyone! I did that and it got rid of the error but still didn't solve my total problem. Thanks again